# What is the original of "Sold Out" by poet Mo Mo?

Tags: translation

I was suddenly reminded of [this poem](http://writing.upenn.edu/epc/rift/rift04/ping0401.html#copyright) today:

> Mo Mo
>
> **SOLD OUT**
>
> I sell dreams, cheap
> following my inclinations like a dog who sold his master
> I sell epochs,
> my body crosshatched with scars
> I sell time, diarrhetic
> penniless as fresh air
> I sell country, motherland disappears
> I sell space, earth vanishes
> I hold the universe in my hand and write you a love letter
>
> I sell holidays, together with loneliness
> in ignorance of the world
> I sell everything:
> life, breath, death
> But tonight you must listen
> I'm going to kiss you seriously
> and turn over like a sunken boat
> You're the ocean
> the only thing I have left
>
> translated by Wang Ping and Lewis Warsh

I believe that Wang Ping is: [王屏](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_Ping_(author)) but I'm not totally sure. I don't know who Mo Mo is or could be. Some other details on the source material:

> Avant-Garde Chinese Poetry
> 1982-1992: 6 Poets
> Translated by Wang Ping

But I think it was actually published in:

> New Generation: Poems from China Today, 1999

Any ideas? Who is Mo Mo? What was the original of "Sold Out"?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick search, 默默 is the pen name for the poet 朱伟国 of the [撒娇派](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E6%92%92%E5%A8%87%E6%B4%BE), a certain school of modern Chinese poetry:

- [Poetry International Archives](https://www.poetryinternational.org/pi/poet/29994/Mo-Mo/en/tile)
- [iFeng Culture](https://culture.ifeng.com/poet/detail_2012_02/21/12663755_0.shtml)

I wasn't able to find a list of his oeuvre though.